# How to solve this combination equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the equation

$$
2n\cdot\binom{n}{0} + 5(n-1)\binom{n}{1}+13(n-2)\binom{n}{2}+\cdots + \left(2^{n-1} + 3^{n-1}\right)\binom{n}{n-1} = 1685.
$$

or using alternative notion for binomial coefficients:

$$
2nC_{n}^0 + 5(n-1)C_n^1 + 13(n-2)C_n^2 +\cdots + \left(2^{n-1} + 3^{n-1}\right) C_n^{n-1}=1685.
$$

where, $n$ is a natural number. I do not know how to solve this. How do I tell Mathematica to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the summation, Mathematica can obtain a closed form, then we can use `Reduce` or `FindInstance` to get the answer:

```
Sum[(2^i + 3^i)*(n - i)*Binomial[n, i], {i, 0, n - 1}]
```

> (1/12)*(4*3^n + 3*4^n)*n

```
Reduce[% == 1685, n, Integers]
```

> n == 5

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
Manipulate[
 Solve[FunctionExpand@
    Sum[(2^i + 3^i) (n - i) Binomial[n, i], {i, 0, k}] == 1685, n, 
  Integers], {k, 1, 50, 1}]
```